# What type of data protocol is inside ChannelData when webrtc completely uses turn relay?

Tags: webrtc, turn

What type of data protocol is inside ChannelData when webrtc completely uses turn relay?
Does not look like SRTP;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ChannelData` messages will contain all the messages you would see on a non-TURN WebRTC call. The WebRTC Agent sends the same messages as usual. Only the ICE Agent is aware that it is communicating via TURN.

Inside the ChannelData messages you will have `STUN` (Used by ICE) `DTLS` and `SRTP`.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing me the actual srtp communication with the webrtc data channels specification. The data channels except binary and text data so you can just send any type of text Json for binary data across the data channel. Data channels themselves do not have stun or dtls or srtp messages on them.

Comment: `ChannelData` isn’t for WebRTC DataChannels. It is a message to or from a TURN server with relayed data. You can see who the Channel was created for in the `ChannelBind`. WebRTC DataChannel messages will be SCTP inside DTLS `ApplicationData`

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5766#section-11.4 is the IETF doc on ChannelData, might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I totally misunderstood the question.

Comment: No worries, it is a tricky and niche subject :)

Comment: Yeah for sure. I worked with webrtc for years, but primarily on the browser as a consumer and not on implementation of the protocols so my understanding of the lower level pieces is weaker than I'd like.